# How to add to stdObject array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the result of print_r($object):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [title] => Test procedures in watermelons
        [nid] => 494
        [type] => chsmanuscript
      )

    [1] => stdClass Object
      (
        [title] => How to eat cookies
        [nid] => 520
        [type] => chsmanuscript
      )
)
```

How can I manually add a 3rd object item in this object array?  I have tried the below but it does not work:

```
$object[2]->title = 'test';
$object[2]->nid   = '999';
$object[2]->type  = 'chsmanuscript'
```

The error is: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DatabaseStatementBase as array

Comment: Something doesn't look right. Does that `print_r ($object)` appear right before `$object[2]->title`? And are you sure the line number for the `DatabaseStatementBase` error matches the code you've identified?

Comment: Yes, I purposely left out some information. This is the result from running a Drupal function called db_query. Nonetheless, it is okay because I just need to know how to do this from a PHP perspective, and what Tim Cooper suggested worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first create a new `stdClass` object in the specific array element before you try to access it's members:

```
$object[2] = new stdClass();
$object[2]->title = 'test';
$object[2]->nid   = '999';
$object[2]->type  = 'chsmanuscript'
```

Comment: I'm not sure `$object` is a simple array considering the error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DatabaseStatementBase as array`

Comment: This is correct if `$object` really is the array shown. The error message makes it look like `$object` is an instance of DatabaseStatementBase, so I think we're missing some context.

Comment: Yes, I purposely left out some information.  This is the result from running a Drupal function called db_query.  Nonetheless, it is okay because I just need to know how to do this from a PHP perspective, and what Tim Cooper suggested worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $object[] = (object)array('title'=>'test', 
                   'ndid'=>'999',
                   'type'=> 'chsmanuscript');
```

This pushes to the array , if you need it to push at the third position, specify that in in $object[#]

Comment: This one is great. What I like about this is that I can add to my existing stdObject array without having to worry what key I am in as it increments itself.

Comment: By using $object[], it pushes to the last position automatically, you could also use array_push(), but [] is shorthand...and thats what you just said haha whoops echo! If it answered gimme the accept!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this

```
$object[2] = (object)array('title'=>'test', 'nid'=>'999', 'type'=>'chsmanuscript');
```